# Why does rearranging Euler's identity in this manner result in a false statement?

Tags: complex-numbers, fake-proofs, wolfram-alpha

I placed each of the following steps into Wolfram alpha after working it out in my head. All steps prior to the one marked with the (*) held true.

$$e^{i \pi} = -1$$

$$e^{2i \pi} = 1$$

$$\ln(e^{2i \pi}) = \ln(1)$$

$$\tag {*} 2i\pi = 0$$

Every conclusion that can be drawn from the last statement is trivially false (such as $i = 0$ or $1 = 0$ etc.). Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Define the function $\ln$ as rigorously as you can, please - that will tell us how to aim the answer.

Comment: In general, on complex numbers the logarithm is a multivalued function, and normally you first need to specify a branch +$2z\pi i$, $z\in\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: I had to do some reading up to understand what you guys meant. Still studying for my major in math and physics so I wasn't aware that complex numbers have to be treated differently when taking logs. I'm still thinking of functions as graphs instead of maps and abstract mathematical objects.

Comment: Bottom line is... Complex numbers are weird, man.

Comment: $2\pi i$ is one of the infinitely many logarithms of $1$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have $$
\sin(2\pi)=\sin(0).
$$
Then $2\pi=0$?

The logarithm, if you care to define it, is not one-to-one.

Comment: Rather it's not a function.